# Heroku SSL certificate error custom domain

Tags: php, ssl, heroku, certificate

It was working fine an hour or so but now I seem to be getting a certificate error that's complaining that the certificate is from "*.herokuapp.com" and not the custom domain. Using the Automated certificate thing.

Suggestions?

Comment: What is the output from `heroku certs:auto`?

Comment: @Chris The "common names" are correct and in the certificate list it says "Cert Issued".

Comment: Where are you seeing a certificate error?

Comment: @Chris I got the error when visiting the site, but now it seems like it randomly started to work again (it wasn't 1 minute ago lol). Thanks for the replies though. :)